# How many objects these Computer Vision API can detect?

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services, google-vision, vision

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-object-detection

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer

I would want to know how many and which objects are recognizable using theses APIs and I can't find a mention of that fact.

I found that google API use https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/ which is based on schema.org types but I don't really understand well what it's all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but as far as I know, there is no fixed list of classes that Azure Computer Vision is able to detect.

By the way, even if there was one, **this list is evolving on a regular basis** (but no schedule is announced).

In any case, there are limitations (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-object-detection?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#limitations)):

> It's important to note the limitations of object detection so you can
> avoid or mitigate the effects of false negatives (missed objects) and
> limited detail.
>
> - Objects are generally not detected if they're small (less than 5% of
>   the image).
> - Objects are generally not detected if they're arranged
>   closely together (a stack of plates, for example).
> - Objects are not differentiated by brand or product names (different
>   types of sodas on a store shelf, for example). However, you can get
>   brand information from an image by using the Brand detection feature.

If you want to detect specific objects, I would highly suggest using `Custom Vision` (doc / overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/home?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)), not `Computer Vision`, where you can train your model with your own images to match what you are trying to detect